# solve a tech gig coding question named Hide and Seek

Tags: data-structures

As usual, Tom and Jerry are fighting. Jerry has K guests at his home for a party. They all are disturbing Tom and enjoying the mood to the max. Tom is angry now and decides to beat all of them. The hole of mouse Jerry is at a distance N from Tom. Tom can beat multiple mouse at a time. But there are some rules in this whole process. The rules are:

1. At a time only one creature can move either any of the relative or Torn.
2. All of them can move only one unit distance at a time.
3. Multiple relatives of jerry can be at the same distance.

If the mouse reaches the hole it will be saved else if Tom reaches them they would be beaten. They will always play in an alternate manner starting with the mouse. Like the first mouse moves one distance then Tom moves one distance. You have to find the most optimized approach and tell the maximum number of mouse that can be saved. Tom stops beating once he reached the hole.

Note: Consider all of them are on a single number line.

Input Format

The first line contains N and K, representing the distance of the hole from Tom and the number of guests

respectively. The next line contains K space-separated integers, x, representing the distance of ith mouse from Tom.

Constraints

2<= N = 10^9

1<< K <= 10^5

1<=x<N

Outout Format
Print Maximum number of mouse that can reach the hole before Tom and save their life.

Sample Test Case1

Input

2 4

1 1 1 1

Output

1

Please help to solve this

Comment: *"Please help to solve this"*: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.